# How to set-up Visual Code to debug GAE apps that use dev_appserver.py

Tags: google-app-engine, visual-studio-code, dev-appserver

Over the years there have been various approaches to getting GAE dev_appserver.py to run/debug under MSVC. Running is easy enough but any breakpoints set are ignored unless workarounds/configuration files are added.

In 2019, how does one get Visual Code to stop on breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

the use of `dev_appserver.py` is no longer recommended by Google.

Just run `main.py` from ms code and breakpoints will work.